# HTML5 <audio> element does not load files on page

Tags: php, html

I am running into [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLu3x.png) with uploading my .mp3 files to an  element on a PHP server. Essentially there is [no response from the server to the GET URL request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaBmE.png) I am wondering what could possibly be the cause of this error. 6 files appear to load just fine. I am using the same HTML code for all of the files-- the loading and not loading files. I have tried changing the php.ini file `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini` and the upload_max_filesize and max_file_uploads attributes to no avail. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Source code:

```html
<div class="row spacer">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <h2>Conducting Audio</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <img class="audio-image" src="img/IMG_4717.JPG" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h4>Tchaikovsky - Symphony No. 5 in e minor, Op. 64</h4>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>1st movement: Andante; Allegro con anima</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/tchaikovsky_symphony_no5_mvt1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>2nd movement: Andante cantabile</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/tchaikovsky_symphony_no5_mvt2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>3rd movement: Valse; Allegro moderato</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/tchaikovsky_symphony_no5_mvt3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>4th movement: Andante maestoso; Allegro vivace</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/tchaikovsky_symphony_no5_mvt4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>      

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h4>Mahler - Symphony No. 2 in c minor ("Resurrection")</h4>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>1st movement: Allegro maestoso</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/mahler_symphony_no2_1st_mvt.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>2nd movement: Andante moderato</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/mahler_symphony_no2_2nd_mvt.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h4>Stravinsky - The Rite of Spring</h4>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <!-- Audio track title here -->
      <h6>Part 1: The Adoration of the Earth</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 columns">
      <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/conducting_audio/stravinsky_rite_of_spring_pt_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
      </audio>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: could you post html source code of generated page? have you tested different browsers?

Comment: Sure. I've added it just now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Google Chrome? Old versions of Google Chrome & Chromium have problems with opening a large amount of audio sources. [(source 1)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779) [(source 2)](http://www.quora.com/Miguel-Paraz/answers/HTML5). Also I recommend for you [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) article from MDN. They wrote about fallbacks and error handling.

Some libraries for media:

- [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/)
- [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/)

Comment: I use Chrome but when I just view the page as just an .html file locally, all of them render correctly. My Chrome is also up to date. Safari seems to be able to open all of them properly. I am going to try those links that you provided now.